# Android sync list views using scrollTo

Tags: android, listview

I am trying to develop an android activity containing two list views.

The requirement is that when one list view is scrolled by user, the other list view should scroll as well by the same amount.

To programmatically scroll the other list view, I am using 'scrollTo(x, y)' method on the other 'ListView'. However, using this method new list view items do NOT get displayed though the amount of scroll is correct.

The problem is easily reproducible when trying to scroll a single 'ListView' programmatically (e.g. on a button click event).

```
String[] values = { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4", "Item 5",
    "Item 6", "Item 7", "Item 8", "Item 9", "Item 10", "Item 11",
    "Item 12", "Item 13", "Item 14", "Item 15", "Item 16",
    "Item 17", "Item 18", "Item 19", "Item 20", };
mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);

mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.activity_example_list);
mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

On click event ...

```
mListView.scrollTo(0, 150);
```

Before 'scrollTo'
Item 1
Item 2
Item 3
Item 4
Item 5
Item 6
Item 7
Item 8
Item 9
Item 10

After 'scrollTo' new items (for instance, Item 11 etc.) are not displayed though the list view scrolls.

Item 3
Item 4
Item 5
Item 6
Item 7
Item 8
Item 9
Item 10
Blank space
Blank space

Please suggest.

Comment: Can you use a single ListView where each item (row) has two columns?

Comment: No, as I enclose the second ListView in a HorizontalScrollView and LinearLayout so that second ListView can be horizontally scrolled while the first ListView remains fixed.

Comment: you could have a horizontal scroll view inside a list item.

Comment: want to scroll entire second ListView horizontally NOT a list item.